# Angular Headers on Application Init

Tags: angular

I am developing an intranet Angular 4 application. My company has third party software for storing the current user's information. And they place the username in header requests. In Angular, when my application is initialized, how do I grab header data? I would like to store the username for my service programs.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you have implemented so far?

Comment: What do you mean by header ? title ? or url parameter ?

Comment: When user's click my link inside our intranet, it will it open my application in a new tab and send me in the HTTP header fields when it requests my website it will send me things like: Request URL, Request Method, Status, Address, and in another field is the user ID that is currently logged in. The third party software will take care of all user permissions, if the user does not have high enough authority it will not let them access my application. But if they do, and when my application is initialized I need to find out who I am talking to, take the user, and save it for later use.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have put up your question seems a bit confusing to me . The scneario you are explaining seems to me implementing authorization security in your app.

When one implement the basic authorization he need to send the username or password in the header. 
And as you said you use thirds party software to store the username.

What you can do is to get the username from third party give an api call in app.service and save in the browser session storage and later using HttpInterceptor you can modify your request and add the username in the header.

Hope it will help